# Python module sqlite3 cannot be found, but is listed

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

I'm trying to run a python application, but I'm getting an error that points to sqlite3 not existing. This is odd since sqlite3 has come standard with Python since 2.5. I am running Python 2.7.11. I can list Python modules and see sqlite3 using

```
pydoc modules
```

But I get the following error:

```
>>> import sqlite3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from dbapi2 import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 28, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: No module named _sqlite3
```

I tried to resolve this by installing pysqlite, as suggested by another user.

```
pip install pysqlite
```

But I encountered another error:

```
src/connection.h:33:21: error: sqlite3.h: No such file or directory
```

Which brings me back to my initial confusion.

Comment: Your second error 'sqlite3.h' No such file or directory is because you are missing some header files. If you run ubuntu you should install package libsqlite3-dev

Comment: I'm on RHEL, so there is likely an equivalent. And I will check if this is a duplicate.